# How can I know the length of a line with different weight depending on a raster?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

How can I know the length of a line with different weight depending on a raster?

I have a line that crosses some areas with different environmental weight.

[image: Line crossing the area]

The values of the different areas in the raster are 1-5 and i want to know how many meters go over each type of area and multiply it for different values depending the raster value.

Comment: Is the map colourcoded, or are the values actually attached?

Comment: This is untested so I am adding it as a comment and not an answer.  1.  Use Split Lines By Maximum Length to divide your line (in the same CRS as your raster) into meters  https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#split-lines-by-maximum-length. 2.  Add and use SAGA tools in QGIS - Profiles from Lines https://saga-gis.sourceforge.io/saga_tool_doc/2.2.5/ta_profiles_4.html to populate the line with the raster values.  3. Dissolve the resulting lines by the raster values.  4.  Calculate the resulting lengths.

Answer (score 1):

This should work if your line layers extent isnt huge. If so the conversion of the raster to polygons will be slow.

1. Clip the raster with the extent of your line layer
2. Convert the raster to polygons
3. Intersect them with your line layer
4. Aggregate to calculate line length per raster value

[image]